# Laravel 5.4: Can't get Auth::guard to work as expected

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am using `Auth::guard` to check which guard is being used in the logout controller. If it is an admin guard, then I wish to redirect to the admin login, otherwise it goes to a users login.

My expectation is that `Auth::guard('admin')` checks to see if the guard is indeed of type admin. If so it progresses with the if statement.

However, it is not working the way I expect. I check my guard with a `dd(Auth::guard())` and it is definitively a `web` guard. BUT regardless, the `Auth::guard('admin')` is still letting it through.

What am I doing wrong? Is my assumption re `Auth::guard` wrong? Many Thanks !

```
if (Auth::guard('admin') ) {

        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();  

        return redirect('admin-login');
    }
    else {

        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();  
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Auth::guard('admin')` it grabs the that guard *if it exists* it doesn't check if that guard is currently being used. Since that guard does exists `if (Auth::guard('admin') )` will always be true.

To check if that guard is currently in use you can do `if(Auth::getDefaultDriver() === 'admin')`. When you use the `auth:admin` middleware it sets `admin` to the be the default guard so you can check against that.

A more DRY way to do this would be:

```
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();  

    return redirect(Auth::getDefaultDriver() === 'admin' ? '/admin-login' : '/login')
```

Comment: thanks for the rapid reply. `Auth::getDefaultGuard` appears not to exist:

FatalThrowableError in AuthManager.php line 294: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::getDefaultGuard()

Comment: @Vince you're right, my mistake. It should be `getDefaultDriver()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: We had a national internet outage yesterday afternoon, just as I was about to respond to you :(   looking at the Laravel api, getDefaultDriver does not get the guard name, it gets the driver ie session or token.  Looking the AuthenticatesUsers.php line 170, there is a function Auth::guard() which does get the guard. If I call that function, and do  dd($this->guard()); I get an object ( array?) which does contain the guard name. check it out in pastebin: [link] https://pastebin.com/piDD7A4f [/link]
**Question** How do I extract the name out of the object/array? Many thanks !

Comment: Did you try `getDefaultDriver()`? When I run it I get the string of the guard name ex 'web' or 'api', not the driver like you say. It returns the value stored in `config/auth.php['defaults']['guard']`. That value gets updated when you use the `auth:admin` middleware using the [shouldUse('admin')](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php#L194) method. Look at the framework source code for [getDefaultDriver()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php#L183). It's grabbing the current guard, not the driver.

Comment: yes - you are right. It looks like I have a totally different problem: my admin login is using the admin guard, yet somehow which I do not understand, when it comes to logout, it is showing up as 'web'. somewhere in the mix admin is getting switched out for web. Is that possible ? Do you go onto laracasts forums at all ? I ask as it is easier to present things there than on SO.

Comment: I don't have an account there, but if you start a thread and link it I'll create one. How is the admin guard set up? and How are you applying it?

Comment: I have an account on Laracasts forum but no one knows how to fix this problem - you are my only hope. :o)  Multi authentication on Laravel is a major headache for *everyone* so there will be many people interested in this conversation. Here is the link to the topic: [link] https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-does-authguard-work?page=1#reply-335753[/link]  I have presented my guard set up as asked. Obviously go to the very bottom of the page, where I will pick up from where we are now.  I have a new question for you :o)  MANY THANKS !!!